# Finding odds of wire ratings with standard distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

A supplier for a factory produce wires with actual population rating of 0.6. Given the wire rating has standard normal distribution, what are the odds for a sample of 52 having an average rating of 0.62 or higher?

This is a practice exam problem I am having trouble with. I know how to find the standard normal distribution but am not sure how to use that information to find the probability required. I'm not looking for an exact answer only a guidlining solution for studying.